# What have I done wrong when coding this array of objects in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, object, nullpointerexception, initialization

I have two classes, PersonnelLists and Employee. I create an instance of PersonnelLists in my main, like so:

```
int main() {
    PersonnelLists example; //Make a personnel list
...
}
```

PersonnelLists uses a constructor with member initialisation of a list of employees, the number of employees, and the size of the array:

```
PersonnelLists::PersonnelLists(): List(new Employee[SIZE]), numEmployees(0), arraySize(SIZE){
}
```

This results in some null empty employees being created (I think?):

```
Employee::Employee(): employeeNumber(0), name(NULL), department(NULL) {
}
```

It is at this line that I get an invalid null pointer error.

I am new with C++, fresh off the boat from Java programming. I'm still a novice with pointers, so I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here.

UPDATE:
As requested, here is the class definition of Employee:

```
#include <iostream>

class Employee {
    public:
        Employee(); //constructor
        Employee(std::string name, std::string deparment);
        void Print() const; //Print this employee's details
        void setEmployeeNo(int employeeNum);

    private:
        int employeeNumber;
        std::string name;
        std::string department;
};
```

Comment: We need the various declarations for Employee, PersonnelLists and List to give you meaningful advice.

Comment: My recommendation would be to just avoid (raw) pointers.  In this case, you could probably use a `std::vector<Employee>` instead of an array.  When you have just one object, a `std::shared_ptr<T>` will act an awful lot like a Java object reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, `new Employee[SIZE]` creates an array of `null` *references*.

In C++, `new Employee[SIZE]` creates an array of default-constructed *instances* of `Employee`. Your default constructor tries to set `name` and `department` to `NULL`. Attempting to initialize a `std::string` to `NULL` would give the error you describe.

There's no "null" string in C++, but you could default-construct `name` and `department`, which would set them to empty strings:

```
Employee::Employee(): employeeNumber(0), name(), department() {
```

Finally, if `List` can contain a variable number of elements, I would recommend that you use `std::vector<Employee>` (which is similar to `ArrayList<Employee>` in Java).

Comment: I suspect that name and department are std::string

Comment: @NPE if I simply don't set name and department in employee, will this fix my error?

Comment: @Chucky and you try to initialize them by NULL? Here you go

Comment: This is a model answer. I will switch to vector eventually. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If `name` and `department` are `std::string`s (or a similar string type), then initializing them with `NULL` (a null character pointer) is invalid.

If I guessed right, you should default-initialize them instead, as:

```
Employee::Employee(): employeeNumber(0), name(), department() {
}
```

But we really can't tell without seeing the class definition of `Employee`.

As others have pointed out, you should use a `std::vector` instead of an array. That allows you to only 
 have valid `Employee` objects in your "list".

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the actual definitions of your classes are, so it's kind of hard to identify your problem.

But an option in modern C++ of doing that is to use a `std::vector<Employee>` data member inside `PersonnelList` class. `std::vector` can grow dynamically at runtime, using its `push_back()` method, e.g.

```
#include <vector> // for std::vector

class Employee
{
  ....
};

class PersonnelList
{
public:
    PersonnelList()
    {
        // Nothing to do - vector is initialized empty
    }

    // Get current employee count
    size_t Count() const
    {
        return m_employees.size();
    }

    // Add a new employee to the personnel
    void AddEmployee(const Employee& newEmployee)
    {
        m_employees.push_back(newEmployee);
    }

private:
    std::vector<Employee> m_employees;
};
```

No need to use raw pointers or something similar: robust RAII STL container classes make your code simpler.

Comment: I will look into using vector in future but at the moment I have a set size array of 10 employees (which will lead to error, I know)